# Перевод строки массива в строку

Tags: python

Пытаюсь реализовать шифр Виженера, но в цикле не могу перевести строку массива в обычную строку, как можно это реализовать?
В моём коде переводит весь массив от индекса и до конца. Я так понял что ошибка в срезе.

```
from itertools import cycle
from string import ascii_uppercase
letter = cycle(ascii_uppercase)

column1 ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
len_other_columns = len(column1)-1
other_columns = range(len_other_columns)
two_d_array = [[c] for c in column1]
for sublist in two_d_array:
    while next(letter) != sublist[0]: ...
    for _ in other_columns:       sublist.append(next(letter))

Table=two_d_array
dictAlph={}
a=0
for item in column1[:]:
 dictAlph.update({a:item})
 a+=1
print(Table)
print(dictAlph)
key="WORLDI"
text="MYTEXT"
res=""
i=0
for item in text[:]:
    indx=column1.index(key[i])
    print(indx)
    j=0
    for item1 in Table[indx:len(column1)]:
        print(Table[i][j])
        print(res)
        if Table[i][j]==text[i]:
            str=list(Table[indx:len(column1)])
            print(str)
            res+=Table[indx][str.index(text[i])]
            break
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

Место в котором ошибка:

```
if Table[i][j]==text[i]:
    str=list(Table[indx:len(column1)])
    print(str)
    res+=Table[indx][str.index(text[i])]
    break
```

Comment: покажите проблемное место с примером входных и выходных данных

Comment: Что такое строка массива?

Comment: @mkkik под строкой я имел ввиду элементы от Table[indx][0] до Table[indx][25], 25 - это количество символов в англоязычном алфавите